# Producer-consumer with one producer and several consumers

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to implement, by using asyncio, a Producer-Consumer model that allows a producer to put `n` items in a queue, and then create `n` consumers that process the `n` items in a concurrent way.

This is my attempt so far:

```py
import asyncio
import uuid
import time
import random


async def produce(q, interval=1):
    while True:
        n = random.randint(0, 20)
        for _ in range(n):
            await q.put((uuid.uuid4().hex, time.perf_counter()))
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)


async def consume(item, t):
    print(f"Managing {item}...")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"Item managed after {time.time() - t:.2f} s")


async def manage_events(q):
    while True:
        item, t = await q.get()
        print(f"Consuming {item}. In queue: {time.perf_counter() - t}")
        task = asyncio.create_task(consume(item, time.time()), name=str(item))
        print("After manage_item")


async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(produce(q, 2), manage_events(q))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - s
    print(f"{__file__} executed in {elapsed:0.2f} seconds")
```

Every `interval` seconds, 0 to 20 items are created and put in the Queue `q`. In the function `manage_events`, every time an item is extracted from the queue, an async task is created in order to consume the item.

This works very well, but my problem is that, when seeing the concurrency diagram, the tasks that consumed the first of the items are not dying after that consumption is complete, so the tasks are running forever in a zombie state doing nothing, and I can't figure out why. The expected and desired behaviour is that a task dies after function `consume`is finished.

---- EDIT ---

This is the code after applying the suggests given by user4815162342

```
import asyncio
import uuid


async def consume(item):
    print(f"Consuming {item}")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"{item} consumed")


async def hello(n):
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print(f"Finishing hello {n}")


async def check_events(interval=1):
    while True:
        item = uuid.uuid4().hex
        print(f"Producing item")
        asyncio.create_task(consume(item))
        print('Tasks count: ', len(asyncio.all_tasks()))
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)


async def main():
    await check_events()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

It turns out that the tasks were effectively dying at the end of every consume() execution, but the PyCharm graph visualizer does not reflect that behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queue architecture is non-standard and doesn't achieve the purpose of a queue. Normally a queue is associated with a fixed number of *producers* and a fixed number of *consumers*. Each consumer fetches queue items in a loop, which is either infinite or terminated by cancellation or a sentinel value. Consumers normally process items sequentially, meaning they use `await` rather than `create_task`. This ensures that you have parallelism that matches the number of workers, and that items are processed in a FIFO manner.

Your queue has a single consumer which immediately spawns a processing async function (which you call consumer), and doesn't wait for it. In this setup you don't need a queue in the first place, you could just call `asyncio.create_task(consume(...))` directly in the producer. Also, if you ever decide to use a bounded queue to ensure backpressure, it will be ineffective because `create_task()` simply pushes the work to asyncio's internal queue which is unbounded.

> This works very well, but my problem is that, when seeing the concurrency diagram, the tasks that consumed the first of the items are not dying after that consumption is complete, so the tasks are running forever in a zombie state doing nothing,

Unlike POSIX processes, asyncio doesn't have the concept of a "zombie state" for its tasks, so you are probably referring to the `manage_events` coroutine which fetches items from the queue in an infinite loop - much like what a typical consumer should do. To terminate it cleanly once all items are done, you can use a sentinel value, such as `None`. That means that at the end of `producer` you can add `await q.put((None, None))` and in `manage_events` you can put `if item is None: break`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Maybe I should have explained better the purpose of the algorithm.  I need to process the items in the queue as fast as possible when they are created. Due to the nature of the items being consumed, the process can take from seconds to hours. If I encounter an item that takes several hours to process, I would like to process the new items in the queue using the concurrency that asyncio provides. I have a threading version of this algorithm working perfectly, I am just exploring another options.

Comment: @AlanWik That makes sense, but then you don't need a queue at all - as I mentioned, you can just call `create_task(consume(...))` in the producer. (Tasks are cheap to create in asyncio, which you already know since you're creating a task for each item in `manage_events()` already.) And getting rid of the queue will eliminate the problem where `manage_events` remains hanging. Am I missing something?

Comment: I see your approach of deleting the queue, and indeed is simpler and works pretty well. I am using PyCharm as IDE, and it has an option to observe the asyncio concurrency graph. What I am observing, is that every task created is still alive once the item is already processed. Is this a normal behaviour? In the threading version, once the task is complete and the execution of the consume() function finishes, the thread simply dies.

Comment: Ok, after some tests. I have discovered that the asyncio graph viewer of PyCharm is bugged. By printing the number of tasks, I have concluded that, once a function executed by means of ```create_task(foo())``` finishes, the task is marked as done and effectively dies. Thanks again for your time, I'm marking your answer as the solution for the tips given.

Comment: @AlanWik It's not normal - when a coroutine returns, the task should be done as well. Does that happen with the toy version of the code or with the version that does the actual work? Also, please note that you didn't show the modified code.

Comment: @AlanWik A possible explanation is that the concurrency graph is overzealous. As you never await the tasks (or access their result using `task.result()`), perhaps the IDE considers them unreaped in the sense that their return values or exceptions they raised (if any) are effectively getting ignored.